# Ошибка компиляции при попытке использования библиотечного класса

Tags: scala

Здравствуйте, решил постигать SCALA (мультипарадигменный язык, надстройка над Java). Первый мой класс и я уже не могу его написать. IDE выдает ошибки:

> not found: type List
> illegal inheritance from sealed class List

На 1-й и 3-й строчках кода. Листинг ниже:

```
case class MyList extends List[Int]{

  def squareList (xs: List[Int]):List[Int]= {
    xs map (x=> x*x)
  }

}
```

Так же IDE почему-то кажется, что тип List определен в моем классе (!!!), естественно, его там нет, и он не видит его. Но как это может быть? Мне нужен стандартный класс из библиотек SCALA. Как тогда использовать такой тип и написать метод, работающий со списками типа Int? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: А что Вы от него хотите? Т.е. нафига тут `case`? Если Вы хотите переопределить `List`, то это зря

Comment: Я бы ворнингам IDE (в отличие от ворнингов компилятора) не сильно доверял. Поддержка языка средами пока слабовата и у синтаксического анализатора часто бывают "ложные срабатывания".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not found: type List illegal inheritance from sealed class List

Суть ошибки в том, что вы пытаетесь наследоваться от `sealed`-класса List. Более того, для выполнения задачи, наследование и не требуется.

Comment: Похоже стартёр топика потерял интерес к вопросу, а мне так хотелось понять, что же он пытался написать.

Comment: Оу, спасибо, ребята. Я уже потерял надежду, что ответят..

Comment: Отрабатывал примеры по тутору по SCALA. Нужно было реализовать что-то у типа List.